# Knockout.js Observing members of a pre-existing API object

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have written a large data API used in several locations outside of our web application and I would like integrate knockout into the application. It seems with knockout, you can create a model with observables. What I can't figure is a way to observe pre-existing values in our API. Is this even possible or do I need to an intermediate model to push data back and forth? That seems highly inconvenient and inefficient. Am I missing something obvious?

In the code below, I would like to observe the name attribute. I'd love suggestions on the best approach here?

**EDIT:** The approach preferred would be to attach observers to already existing attributes rather then writing my API around knockout or writing an additional wrapper on top of the API. This API is shared with some non-browser applications and I think that eliminates the possibility of writing the entire API using knockout without adding additional complexities. I am open to considering other frameworks that can do what I need.

```
myAPI.user = {
    ...
    get name() {
        return myAPI.user.object.name;
    },
    set name(x) {
       myAPI.user.setProperty('name', x);
    }
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom `computed`.

```
var VM = function() {
   this.apiUserName = ko.computed({
       read: function() { return myAPI.user.object.name; },
       write: function(value) { return myAPI.user.setProperty('name', value); },
       owner: this
   });
}
```

Now if `myAPI.user.object.name` changes and you have an event for it, call `valueHasMutated`.

```
// inside your event
vm.apiUserName.valueHasMutated();
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you are telling me valueHasMutated would need to be called if name changes from an external source outside.

Comment: He's saying to call it if `myAPI.user.object.name` changes, so that Knockout will be notified of the change.

Comment: @Daniel A. White While this solution does work, I really don't like it very much because it adds another layer of complexity. I would just rewrite the API using knockout so I'm not duplicating the wrapper but I'm not sure what the effects are in non browser based applications using javascript. It seems unfortunate that I can't simply attach the event "observer" to already existing attributes or objects. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It seems that this does not work because apuUserName has no method called valueHasMutated()

Comment: can you share how you are calling that?